# Как достать переменную из addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, функции

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){

  let touchStart = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

}, false)
```

Как получить значение `touchStart`, которое является целым числом, чтобы использовать его в другой функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let touchStart;
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){

  touchStart = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

}, false);

function otherFunction() {
  console.log(touchStart);
}
```